# Getting segmentation fault while printing pointer

Tags: c, pointers

While running this C code, I am getting `Segmentation Fault`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int l1=5, l2=5;
    int* c=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(l1+l2));
    int* c_ptr=&c;
    *c_ptr=6;
    c_ptr++;
    *c_ptr=7;
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        printf("%d ", *(c+i));
    }
}
```

I want to know why it is showing `Segmentation Fault`. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: change this line int* c_ptr=&c; to int* c_ptr=c;

Comment: Read your warnings. They will tell you.

Comment: Ok it is working fine, thanks

Comment: `int* c_ptr=&c;` is not even valid C. If you are using gcc make sure to always compile with `-pedantic-errors` so that you get a compiler error each time you write invalid C. Regardless, _never_ ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The reason being you are dereferencing the address 6 then 10 then 14 and then 18 which you do not have access legality. I.e you can not access these addresses with `*` operator.

Simply change

```
int* c_ptr=&c;
```

to

```
int* c_ptr=c;
```

and it will not cause segmentation fault.

Comment: Although,it will fail in first iteration itself when you try dereferencing the address 6 .